# Django Best practices on overriding foreign key form widget to receive user input

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I defined a model that has some foreign keys to other models. Such that I have the following in **models.py**:

```
class Appelation(models.Model):

    appelation = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                              verbose_name=_('Appelation'),
                              validators=[non_numeric],
                              blank=True,
                              unique=True
                             )


class Wine(models.Model):
    appelation = models.ForeignKey(ForeignKeyModel, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Appelation'))
```

**forms.py**

```
class WineForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
        model = Wine

    appelation= CharField(widget=TextInput)
```

**views.py**

```
class WineCreateView(WineActionMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

model = Wine
form_class = WineForm
action = 'created'

def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request.POST = self.request.POST.copy()  # makes the request mutable

    appelationForm = modelform_factory(Appelation, fields=('appelation',))

    form_dict = {
        'appelation': appelationForm
    }
    for k, modelForm in form_dict.iteritems():
        model_class = modelForm.Meta.model
        log.debug('current model_class is: %s' % model_class)
        log.debug('request is %s' % self.request.POST[k])
        try:
            obj = model_class.objects.get( **{k: self.request.POST[k]} )
            log.debug("object exists. %s pk from post request %s " % (model_class,obj.pk))
            self.request.POST[k] = obj.id
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
            log.error('Exception %s' % e)
            f = modelForm(self.request.POST)            
            log.debug('errors %s' % f.errors)
            if f.is_valid():
                model_instance = f.save()
                self.request.POST[k] = model_instance.pk

    return super(WineCreateView,self).post(self.request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Basically, what the view code does is, it tries to create a new Appelation model instance ( which is a fk to Wine) if the one we passed does not exist. and it returns the pk in the field, since we expect a pk, not a string as input.

I want to create appelationForm, because I have some custom validators I need to apply to validate the foreignKey input.

The limitations I see now, Is that I don't see how I can attach the validation errors from appelationForm to the ones of the main form so that they are displayed instead of the ones we would typically have from a foreignKey field.

To see the full example code:

https://github.com/quantumlicht/django-wine/blob/master/project/corewine/models.py
https://github.com/quantumlicht/django-wine/blob/master/project/corewine/forms.py
https://github.com/quantumlicht/django-wine/blob/master/project/corewine/views.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is write a `clean_appelation` method on your `WineForm`, which comprehensively validates the input according to your criteria, i.e. either an existing Appelation id, or a new Appelation name, and raises the appropriate errors. Then in your view, you can assume the form data is valid and will work. This should give you something to start off with:

```
class WineForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    appelation= CharField(widget=TextInput)
    def clean_appelation(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['appelation']
        if data.isdigit():
             # assume it's an id, and validate as such
             if not Appelation.objects.filter(pk=data):
                 raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Appelation id')
        else:
             # assume it's a name
             if ...:
                 raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Appelation name')
        return data
```

Comment: However, I still need to translate the existing Appelation into it's valid foreignKey id right? If yes, this means I still need my view code that check for FK existance and creates it if we need it.

Comment: Yes, you still do the saving in the view, but you don't have to worry about handling any `DoesNotExist` exceptions because you've validated the data in the form.